# Firestore security rules granting access only to users authenticated with Google and that are part of the Firebase project

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using FireCMS for my Firestore and have set up Google authentication. To secure my data, I only wish to grant access to Google users that are part of the Firebase project. I'd also like to avoid listing user emails one by one, if possible.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents/{document=**} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth != null &&
      request.auth.token.firebase != null &&
      request.auth.token.firebase.identities["google.com"] != null;
  }
}
```

But this gives access to all Google accounts, not just those that have been invited to my Firebase project.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to identify that the user is a collaborator on the Firebase project from the information in their Firebase ID token. The security rules also don't have access to the information of your Firebase project.

The only options I can think of are to:

- If you use Identity Platform, you may be able to [disable sign-up](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/settings) - and only leave sign-in enabled. You could then pre-create an account for each collaborator, after you add them to the project.
- Include a custom claim in the token of collaborators, that your security rules then check for. If you don't want to write the code for this yourself, you can consider using extension that let's you [set Auth claims through Firestore](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/experimental-extensions/tree/next/firestore-auth-claims).
- Include information about each collaborator in your Firestore database, and then look it up from there in your security rules, similar to this example on [getting user rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).